# How do I loop through my search results in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a `ProductListPage` component with the goal of showing multiple items when the search returns with the results. I am currently trying to make a loop and the part that I might have wrong is the key, but it could also be another part.

The name of the array of data I am getting back through the search is called result, and I am currently trying to grab onto the 'name' part. I would love to do the image as well, but I am not sure if you can do both in one loop or if I would need to do two. Any tips or help would be much appreciated!

```
const ProductList = ({ result }) => {
  const containerStyles = {
    height: '100vh',
    overflow: 'auto',
    textAlign: 'center',
    padding: '5vh'
  }
  console.log(result)
  return (
    <Grid container direction='column'>
      <div style={containerStyles}>
        {!result
          ? (
            <h1>No results found</h1>
          )
          : (
            <div>{result.map((name, id) => (
              <p key={id}>
                {result.name}
              </p>))}
            </div>
            // <img>{result[0].image}</img>
          )}
      </div>
    </Grid>
  )
}

export default ProductList
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the result array contain objects in the form:

```
{
  name:"",
  id:1,
  image: ""
}
```

Then your map will look like this:

```
{
  result.map((item) => (
          <p key={item.id}>
            {item.name} {item.image}
          </p>
  ))
}
```

Where item is one item in your array You can access any property that exist in that item within the map callback function.

Comment: Actually the OP is trying to solve a totally different problem.

Comment: Oh wow that worked! I am getting the data on the page! I have a follow up question if that is alright. So the image is coming from a url and that is all that is being currently displayed (the url)... would I need to wrap the image in an image tag to get it to show up?

Comment: Yes, you need to construct the UI the way you want it. So put an `<img>` tag in there and place your url in the `src` attribute as you would.

Comment: Erm, @SlothsAreGreat Did you even check my answer? 